# Can I additional configuration files to the default in Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

With Spring, I can include config files with non-default names using the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

/*
This allows us to add an additional configuration file to the default configuration.
By using the `spring.config.name` property, we can specify the order of property files to load from the `spring.config.location` that we specify on startup (if not specified, it assumes the default).  This also respects profiles as well.
*/
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(DirectconnectEdgeserviceApplication.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name:application,secrets")
                .build().run(args);
    }
```

It's using the Spring property `spring.config.name` to specify that the config files will be named `application*` or `secrets*`.

I can probably import `io.micronaut.spring.context` and use MicronautApplicationContext, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in vanilla Micronaut?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I additional configuration files to the default in Micronaut?

Yes.  There are a number of ways to do that.  A common one is to use the `micronaut.config.files` JVM system property to point to files.

```
java -Dmicronaut.config.files="/path/to/someConfig.yml" myapp.jar
```

You could also set the corresponding OS environment variable:

```
export MICRONAUT_CONFIG_FILES=somefile.yml
```

More info at https://docs.micronaut.io/2.1.1/guide/index.html#propertySource.